# Access website using a machine with no internet access

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, internet, proxy

I have two machines, both machines are running **Windows 7**. **Machine A**: has Internet access while **Machine B**: does not have internet access. Machine A and B are in the same network. Machine A access internet by connecting to a proxy server and due to a some reasons I do not want to connect Machine B to the proxy server.

My requirement is  to access a website using Machine B eg: www.yahoo.com. Is there any mechanism I could access this website from Machine B which does not have Internet access by connecting to Machine A which has internet access?

Comment: I suggest one of your tags contain the operating system of your machines or at least you name it in your question, since it is a critical information in suggesting solutions.

Comment: I have updated the question with the OS I'm using

Answer (score -1):

This one is quite easy to accomplish.

First make sure both machines are visible to each other on the network.

If that's the case, go to your network connections overview (network adapters) on Machine A, right-click on your internet Connection (mostly the LAN adapter) and choose properties.
On the second tab in the preferences window, you can check "Allow other users on the network to use this connection as an internet connection."
Be sure to disable the ability for remote computers to change the connection if you do not want that.

All in all, this should be it.

Comment: I can't find a second tab on the properties window, all i can see is a Networking tab in the properties window when right click network adapter and select properties

Comment: I'm getting this type of window http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_eQXGzWycZKM/S7Nb8E_6y2I/AAAAAAAAASY/vaNIGWs7JZc/s320/Windows7-Local-Area-Connections-propertise-ipv4.jpg

Comment: That's really strange, normally you should have a second tab like [this](http://www7.pic-upload.de/29.11.13/f7em9qwpni.png)